# Issues with TDAmeritrade thinkorswim

Tags: 12.04, java

I installed thinkorswim ("ToS") to Ubuntu 10.04LTS on a 64-bit AMD setup in January and used it without issues through August 3. The system was continually kept updated all that time.

In mid-August I attempted to install ToS on a different 64-bit AMD computer under a fresh 12.04 install (with updates).  Although ToS installed and ran, it crashed the system.  The only way to recover is to remove the battery.  Installing Sun Java 6u35 solved the problem (see post "Thinkorswim crashes 12.04"). ToS will now install and run, but the kill button causes the ToS icon to disappear and the only way (that I know of) to restart ToS is to reinstall (run the ToS installer script).  Minimizing also causes problems. The 12.04 update of October 10 has only made the problem worse (kill/minimize/maximize buttons disappear, buttons respond only after very long delay).

Also, ToS will no longer install to a fresh 10.04LTS install. (first observed in mid- to late September on a third 64-bit AMD setup).  The script runs, but the Java installer fails, emitting a message saying that it cannot connect to an X server.  Attempt to install to openSuSE 12.2 fails also.  Installing Sun Java 6 makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Installing is a matter of making sure permissions are set correctly, since the ToS installer doesn't.  If you install to your home directory and allow write and execute permissions in the ~/thinkTDA directory, you should be set.  Ubuntu may ask to confirm ToS as trusted.  Once you confirm that it is, the ToS icon will display on the desktop and/or launchpad.

I have now successfully installed and am using ToS on Ubuntu 12.04 and also Linux Mint 13 "Maya" and Linux Mint 14 "Nadia".  It won't install on openSUSE 12.1.  ToS runs just fine with each native openJDK (both 6 and 7), though pulseaudio sometimes causes exception errors, which require ToS to be restarted.

If ToS requests to be restarted, do so.  If you continue, it will SEGFAULT and you will probably have to remove and then restore power to recover.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it isn't nice to "respond" to one's own posts.  But, here are the solutions:

1. Make sure the subdirectory to which ToS installs (and all its files and lower lever subdirectories) are read-write and execution enabled.
2. Unless you want to install Oracle's Java 6 and link the ToS installer to it, disable the ToS splash screen.  If you can't do that, call Tech Services and ask them to disable it for your account.  Although I have experienced some crashes over the past five months, ToS has been running well for me with the splash screen disabled under Ubuntu 12.04 and the openjdk that comes with it.

Comment: It's perfectly fine to answer your own question, even encouraged.

Comment: Installing is all a matter of making sure permissions are set correctly, since the ToS installer doesn't.  If you install to your home directory and allow write and execute permissions in the ~/thinkTDA directory, you should be set.